# Window service : How to start a Timer at Particular Time

Tags: c#, .net, timer

I have seen similar post of setting Timer at particular time ... I Dont want to run timer Whole Day ...I Want to start it at specific Time ..
 Most of the suggestion is use Scheduled tasks ...but I want to do it with window service ....

Here is My Service Working Code :

```
public AutoSMSService2()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    if (!System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists("MySource"))
    {
        System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource(
            "MySource", "MyNewLog");
    }
    eventLog1.Source = "MySource";
    eventLog1.Log = "MyNewLog";

    Timer checkForTime = new Timer(5000);
    checkForTime.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(checkForTime_Elapsed);
    checkForTime.Enabled = true;
}

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    eventLog1.WriteEntry("In OnStart");
}

protected override void OnStop()
{
    eventLog1.WriteEntry("In onStop."); 
}

void checkForTime_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    eventLog1.WriteEntry("Timer Entry");
}
```

My Timer is working fine and adding Log at 5 sec interval ..But I want to start Timer Lets Say 3:00 PM ...

```
private static void SetTimer(Timer timer, DateTime due) 
{
    var ts = due - DateTime.Now;
    timer.Interval = ts.TotalMilliseconds;
    timer.AutoReset = false;
    timer.Start();
}
```

But I am not sure How to Implement it in Code ..

Any suggestion would be Helpful

Comment: Just check `DateTime.Now` in the elapsed handler to see if it is after 3 PM. If it is, write the log, if not, do nothing.

Comment: Actually I Dont want to run timer at Each 5 minute interval..I Want to start it at specific Time

Comment: You can't, you either check it every interval or you schedule it. There is no way to make it know that the time is now 3PM

Comment: @ Tzah Mama   ohh...Is It ??? :(

Comment: no  it's possible  to achieve  this  I will post a trick just wait I'm coding

Answer (score 0):

here an example with windows form but you  can  achieve the some thing with windows  service

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private bool _timerCorrectionDone = false;
    private int _normalInterval = 5000;  
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //here you calculate the second that should elapsed 
         var now  =  new TimeSpan(0,DateTime.Now.Minute, DateTime.Now.Second);
        int corrTo5MinutesUpper = (now.Minutes/5)*5;
        if (now.Minutes%5>0)
        {
             corrTo5MinutesUpper =  corrTo5MinutesUpper + 5; 
        }
        var upperBound = new TimeSpan(0,corrTo5MinutesUpper, 60-now.Seconds);
        var correcFirstStart = (upperBound - now);
        timer1.Interval = (int)correcFirstStart.TotalMilliseconds;
        timer1.Start();


    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // just do a correction   like  this 
        if (!_timerCorrectionDone)
        {
            timer1.Interval = _normalInterval;
            _timerCorrectionDone = true;  
        }


    }
```

Comment: Thanks KB ... I am Implementing and trying to understand it

Comment: yes I  think  that what's the  OP want to achieve because otherwise the timer ticks are hardware interrupts

Comment: @Tzah ..thats same what i believe ..I think you have set the Interval ..But Not a Specific Time . Rectify me if I am Wrong

Comment: @user3734952 This piece of code will round your timer, if I'm not mistaken, to a complete minute. This _will not_ make your timer start at a specific time. If this is the behavior you wanted then I misunderstood your question

Comment: ok you can't set it at specific time. but like this you will be sure that the timer will start at 3:00:00PM exactly   and not 3:00:33 PM you can  increase the normal  interval to one hour but you should make a correction to one hour

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it every day, Hope this will help.

```
private System.Threading.Timer myTimer;
private void SetTimerValue ()
{

   DateTime requiredTime = DateTime.Today.AddHours(15).AddMinutes(00);
   if (DateTime.Now > requiredTime)
   {
      requiredTime = requiredTime.AddDays(1);
   }


   myTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(new TimerCallback(TimerAction));
   myTimer.Change((int)(requiredTime - DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds, Timeout.Infinite);
}

private void TimerAction(object e)
{
   //here you can start your timer!!
}
```